# Hit Test behavior

Tags: .net, wpf, hittest

I have the following code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    List<UIElement> ucs = new List<UIElement>();

    private void Window_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender,
        MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ucs.Clear();

        Point p = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);

        VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, null,
            new HitTestResultCallback(MyHitTestCallback),
            new PointHitTestParameters(p));

        Console.WriteLine("ucs.Count = {0}", ucs.Count);

        foreach (var item in ucs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("item: {0}", item.ToString());
        }
    }

    HitTestResultBehavior MyHitTestCallback(HitTestResult result)
    {
        ucs.Add(result.VisualHit as UIElement);
        return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue;
    }
}
```

this is my window

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <my:UserControl1 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="82,88,0,0" x:Name="userControl11" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <my:UserControl1 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="168,166,0,0" x:Name="userControl12" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <my:UserControl1 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="231,130,0,0" x:Name="userControl13" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

this is my UC

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="Label" Height="44" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Width="78" Background="#FF4B9FC4" BorderBrush="#FF020A0D" BorderThickness="1" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

this is the output when I click ON A USER CONTROL, then on a intersection of 2 UserControls:

```
ucs.Count = 2
item: System.Windows.Controls.Border
item: System.Windows.Controls.Border
ucs.Count = 3
item: System.Windows.Controls.Border
item: System.Windows.Controls.Border
item: System.Windows.Controls.Border
```

Why this? Where is the UserControl under the mouse instance?

PS:
Now, when I have on the Label the `BorderThickness = 0`

```
ucs.Count = 3
item: System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock
item: System.Windows.Controls.Border
item: System.Windows.Controls.Border
ucs.Count = 3
item: System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock
item: System.Windows.Controls.Border
item: System.Windows.Controls.Border
```

Answer (score 2):

The `UserControl1` is invisible. Its *contents* are visible, but your `UserControl1` instance itself does not have any visuals of its own. (And it never will. A user control's job is really just to contain other things.)

Hit testing only reports elements that make a direct contribution to the visual tree. And since hit testing considers each element in isolation, this means that elements that are acting purely as containers don't show up. (And a related fact is that hit testing only considers the pixels that actually got painted. So if you have a `Border` where you've set the `BorderBrush` and a non-zero `BorderThickness` but you have no `Background`, the hit test will only consider the border outline to be a hit - points inside of the border will not be considered to hit the border because it's not painting anything in its interior.

If you need to do hit testing of a "this thing, or anything inside this thing" style, then either either

1. use mouse enter/leave events - those bubble, and so they will get raised even on invisible container elements
2. use `IsMouseOver` or
3. use the hit test function you're using, passing the user control as the first argument, and treat any hit as an indication that the hit test point is inside the user control

The third one is more complex, but if you need to hit test points other than the one currently under the mouse, you'd need to use it.

Comment: I need to count all MyUserControls under the mouse, directly or indirectly located under the mouse cursor. IsMouseOver will return true only if the element is *directly* under the mouse.

Comment: What do you mean by "indirectly"? IsMouseOver is documented as "including visual children elements that are inside its bounds". I'm wondering if you're looking for bounding box containment, in which case hit testing is the wrong thing. For that, you just want VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds.

Comment: ...or to put it another way, I think WPF hit testing probably does something different from what you want. Could you describe what you want to do, without using the phrase "hit testing" because I think the ambiguity of that term is what's causing confusion here.

Comment: I mean If I need to count Panels and I mouseOver a button in a Panel, the Panel should be counted, as other eventual parent panels., similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323153/count-controls-of-type-a-under-the-mouse-in-wpf

Comment: It's still not really clear to me what you're trying to do. "count Panels" doesn't sound like a user-driven requirement. Are your end users hammering down your door saying "We need this application to count panels!"? Hit testing has some slightly surprising behaviours in WPF, which is why I'm trying to understand what you're really trying to do here.